# Kubernetes volume mount set up Type check failed

Tags: kubernetes

I am unable to deploy an application in kubernetes , this is the deployment yaml.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: openjdk:14
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts: 
        - name: testing
          mountPath: "/usr/src/myapp/docker.jar"
        workingDir: "/usr/src/myapp"
        command: ["java"]
        args: ["-jar", "docker.jar"]        
      volumes: 
      - hostPath: 
          path: /home/user/docker.jar
          type: File
        name: testing
```

This is the error I receive, and I can verify the file does exist and in this folder.
I tried removing the type but it only uploads an empty directory, it seems to not recognize that the file exists.

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "testing" : hostPath type check failed: /home/user/docker.jar is not a file
```

Comment: You might get this issue if Kubernetes cannot find this file. Are you using minikube or some cloud environment?

Comment: Yes , I am using minikube

Comment: Did you create this file in your VM or did you ssh to your minikube VM and crated there?

Comment: Not in the vm I will now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you running on multi-node system, be sure the hostpath is accessible on the **node** that pods deployed to.

I also encountered this very similar issue on one master & one-worker node setup using helm chart.

Helm deployed all pods to **worker** node, and hostPath were not accessible from worker node even though deployment is done from master node.
Copy and verify hostpath on worker node resolved is type of error for me.

Answer (score 3):

When you are starting [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/) with default `docker` driver, you are creating `Docker VM` inside your machine.

#### Background

When you are using your VM your terminal looks like:

```
user@nameofyourhost:~$
```

But if you will `ssh` to your `Minikube VM` terminal looks like below:

```
docker@minikube:~$
```

In [HostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) you have information:

> A hostPath volume mounts a file or directory from the host node's filesystem into your Pod.

In `minikube` when you are using `hostPath`, node is considered not your `machine` but the `Minikube VM` which was created during `minikube start`

#### Tests

As I dont have exactly your files, Ive used `nginx`. Please remember that you should have proper permissions to directories you want to mount. I've used `tmp` as in `nginx` this directory have full access for everyone.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: testing
          mountPath: "/tmp/docker.jar"   #this is path to the file
      volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: <path to docker.jar file> #should be on Minikube VM
          type: File
        name: testing
```

When you create `docker.jar` on VM.

```
user@nameOfMyVM:~$ pwd
/home/user
user@nameOfMyVM:~$ ls
docker.jar
```

When you will chage in `hostpath.path` to `/home/user/docker.jar` it will return warning

```
Warning  FailedMount  4s (x4 over 7s)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "testing" : hostPath type check failed: /home/sekreta/docker.jar is not a file`
```

As Kubernetes didn't find this file.

But when you will create this file inside `Minikube VM`

```
$ minikube ssh
docker@minikube:~$ pwd
/home/docker
docker@minikube:~$ ls
docker.jar
```

and change in deployment `hostPath.path` to `/home/docker/docker.jar` pod will be created.

```
$ kubectl get po
NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
test-c68d959c6-kb275   1/1     Running   0          13s
```

File can be found in directory set in YAML, which is `tmp`.

```
$ kubectl exec -ti test-c68d959c6-kb275 -- bin/bash
root@test-c68d959c6-kb275:/# cd /tmp
root@test-c68d959c6-kb275:/tmp# ls
docker.jar
```

#### Conclusion

When you are using `HostPath` on `Minikube` you need to remember that `filesystem` is not your `Machine` but `Minikube VM` which was created during `minikube start`.

Answer (score 1):

If you verified that the file/directory exists on the Minikube VM (`minikube ssh ls -la /home/user`) then **you are not deploying on the `minikube` k8s context as you are expecting**.

Check what's your currently used context, with `kubectx --current`.

Then set the Minikube one via `kubectx minikube` or `kubectl use-context minikube`.